# What high-lift devices are used on the Bombardier Dash 8 Q400?

Tags: aerodynamics, flaps, slats, dash-8

What type of flaps, slats or other high-lift devices are used on this aircraft?

Comment: I won't post as an answer as I don't have references to hand - but essentially: No slats, and single slotted flaps.

Answer (score 2):

The [Dash8 - Q400 - Aeroplane General](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwj7qJ39ia_MAhUM6SYKHTglAp0QFggyMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smartcockpit.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fpath%3Ddocs%2F%26file%3DQ400-Aeroplane_General.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH4Tw3iAsebig88SxAZIaOTA2p0FA&cad=rja) PDF (courtesy of [smartcockpit.com](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/Q400-Flight_Controls.html)) indicates on page 27 that there are inboard and outboard flaps.

Reading through the [Dash8 - Q400 Flight Controls](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/Q400-Flight_Controls.html) PDF (also from smartcockpit.com) indicates that:

> Two single-slotted inboard and outboard fowler flaps are attached to the trailling edge of each wing (Figure 12.8-1).
> <sup>page 43</sup>

There is no indication of slats or any other high-lift device.